# Grabbing JS values from hidden fields on page load

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, geolocation

I'm trying to implement some Google Maps stuff in .NET for a uni project.

However, I'm struggling with getting my coordinates to my .NET Google Maps control.

I figured the easiest way to do this would be to use the HTML5 geolocation API to get the coordinates of the current position, then grab these in my .NET code and use them to center the map.

I have the following JS code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
            if (Modernizr.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getCoords);
            }
            else {
                // no support
            }

            function getCoords(position) {
                $("#lat").val(position.coords.latitude);
                $("#long").val(position.coords.longitude);
            }
    });
```

This puts the coordinates for lat and longitude in their respective hidden textboxes, `#lat` and `#long`.

Now, I want to grab them in my code-behind .NET code. I'm trying to do it like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        // some other code
    }

    // maps
    addStoreMap.enableDragging = false;
    addStoreMap.enableGoogleBar = false;

    // grab the coordinates here.
    decimal lat = Convert.ToDecimal(hdnLat.Value);
    decimal lng = Convert.ToDecimal(hdnLong.Value);
}
```

However, this always returns an empty value. I can't seem to load the coordinate values into my .NET code. I get the values when I alert them through JS though. Is this because the Page_Load event happens before my JS gets executed? If so, how would I work around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ready` event on `document` has no `.preventDefault()`, so that line is throwing an error. It was never making it to the `geolocation` code. Remove the line:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/mGj2W/

HTML:

```
<input id="lat" type="hidden" /><input id="long" type="hidden" />
<div id="result"></div>
```

Script:

```
$( document ).ready( function () {

    if ( true ) { //modernizr check here

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( getCoords );

    }
    else {

        // no support

    }

    function getCoords( position ) {

        $( '#lat' ).val( position.coords.latitude );
        $( '#long' ).val( position.coords.longitude );

        $( '#result' ).text( $( '#lat' ).val() + ', ' + $( '#long' ).val() );

    }

} );
```

Output:

```
39.583129, -124.4872483
```

Comment: the PreventDefault was some code I accidentally left in from some try with a click event on a button. Sorry about that. I manage to do what you're doing; however, the ASP.NET part is creating the problem here. I can't seem to get my JS values to my .NET code because the Page_Load event seems to get called BEFORE the JS is done loading the coordinates, thus always returning an empty value.

Comment: `Page_Load` is done on the server and `document.ready` is done on the client. They really have nothing to do with each other. You'd have to load your page and then have something post it back to the server. What is triggering the post back?

Comment: I'm not posting anything to the server. I'm just grabbing the values from the hidden fields in my .NET code. Pretty confused about this at the moment.. because if they don't have anything to do with eachother, why won't it give me the right values in .NET code? :( I'll sleep on it and think about it again tomorrow. Thanks for your time!

Comment: When a browser requests your page, it goes to the server, runs your .NET `Page_Load` function, and then sends the result back to the client browser. Then your server does nothing at waits. On the client side, in the users browser, the HTML loads and the javascript is parsed. Your `document.ready` function executes and loads the geo data into your `<inputs>` elements. Then, nothing happens. The client just sits there and so does the server. The client would have to take an action, like click a button, to send the code back to your server when you could get the values.

Comment: ^ That comment made it all so much more clear. I fixed it by adding a button and then submitting the data to the server, where I catch it and render the map. Thank you so much!